# 3D UNet activation function and number classes

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, image-segmentation, unet-neural-network

I am a beginner in deep learning and trying to develop a U-Net model for vessel segmentation (vessel (white pixels), background (black pixels)) on nifti images. I am confused on the defining the number of classes and sigmoid/softmax activation function. Should I set the number of n_classes = 2 and softmax activation function for this or n_classes = 1 and sigmoid activation function? below are the codes for the DataGenerator and UNet model.

```
n_classes = 2
class DataGenerator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

    def __init__(self, img_paths, mask_paths, batch_size, n_classes):
        self.x, self.y = img_paths, mask_paths
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_classes = n_classes

    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(len(self.x) / self.batch_size)

    def read_nifti(self, filepath):
        volume = nib.load(filepath).get_fdata()
        volume = np.array(volume)
        return volume


    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

        image = [self.read_nifti(image_file) for image_file in batch_x]
        image = np.array(image, dtype=np.float32)
        image = tf.expand_dims(image, axis=-1)
        
        label = [self.read_nifti(mask_file) for mask_file in batch_y]
        label = np.array(label, dtype=np.float32)
        label = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(label, num_classes=self.n_classes)
        
        return image, label

'''---------------------build CNN model -------------------'''
def unet3d_model1(nx= 224, ny=224, nz=64):

    inputs = Input((nx, ny, nz, 1))
    conv1 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPool3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2))(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv3D(256, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv4)

    up5 = UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2))(conv4)
    merge5 = concatenate([up5, conv3])
    conv5 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(merge5)
    conv5 = Conv3D(128, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv5)

    up6 = UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2))(conv5)
    merge6 = concatenate([up6, conv2])
    conv6 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(merge6)
    conv6 = Conv3D(64, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv6)

    up7 = UpSampling3D(size=(2, 2, 2))(conv6)
    merge7 = concatenate([up7, conv1])
    conv7 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(merge7)
    conv7 = Conv3D(32, (3, 3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv7)

    conv8 = Conv3D(n_classes, (1, 1, 1), activation='softmax')(conv7)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=conv8)

    return model
```

Answer (score 1):

As you said, a pixel can belong to a vessel pixel or background pixel. So, what makes sense to use a single node with sigmoid activated output layer. With that, you will have a probability of the regarding pixel's "vessel-ness". Then obviously, you need to apply a threshold to extract the vessel image.

Hope that helps.